# Rails - Passing an option to a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a help method that looks a something like this:

```
  def html_format(text, width=15, string="<wbr />", email_styling=false)

    if email_styling
       ...... stuff
    else
       ...... stuff
    end
       ...... stuff
  end
```

I'm having problems sending email_styling as true. Here is what I'm doing in the view:

```
<%= html_format(@comment.content, :email_styling => true) %>
```

Am I passing true incorrectly? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not passing it correctly. You need to do the following:

```
<%= html_format(@comment.content, 15, '<wbr />', true) %>
```

Alternatively you can use an options hash to pass your parameters:

```
def html_format(text, options = {})
  opt = {:width => 15, :string => '<wbr />', :email_styling => false}.merge(options)

  if opt[:email_styling]
    ...
  end
end
```

So that you can make your call like this:

```
<%= html_format(@comment.content, :email_styling => true) %>
```

Comment: But it errors: "undefined local variable or method `width' for #<#<Class:0x1055ff180>:0x1055fd178>
"

Comment: Make sure you replace instances of width, email_styling and string with opt[:width], opt[:email_styling] and opt[:string].

Comment: my mistake, looks like I need to use the opt[:XXX] for inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't have named arguments, so your method call:

```
html_format(@comment.content, :email_styling => true)
```

Is actually calling (psuedo-code):

```
html_format(text = @comment, width = true)
```

You need to specify all your function parameters in order, even if it means redundantly passing some default values:

```
html_format(@comment.content, 15, '<wbr />', true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def html_format(text, user_options={})
  options = {
    :width => 15, 
    :string => "<wbr />", 
    :email_styling => false
  }
  options.merge!(user_options)
  if options[:email_styling]
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

**USAGE**

```
html_format("MY TEXT", {:email_styling => true, :width => 20})
```